# Exposing unmanaged const static std::string in a managed C++ class

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I have a non-.NET C++ class as follows:

Foo.h:

```
namespace foo {
  const static std::string FOO;
  ...
}
```

Foo.cc:

```
using namespace foo;

const std::string FOO = "foo";
```

I want to expose this for use in a C# application, but I keep getting errors about mixed types when I try the following:

FooManaged.h:

```
namespace foo {
  namespace NET {
    public ref class Foo {
      public:
        const static std::string FOO;
    }
  }
}
```

FooManaged.cc:

```
using namespace foo::NET;

const std::string Foo::FOO = foo::FOO;
```

What's the right way to translate an unmanaged string constant to a managed string constant?

Comment: You're declaring the variable incorrectly in Foo.h. It needs to be non-`static` and declared with `extern`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++/CLI, the `literal` keyword is used in place of `static const` where you want the constant definition to be included in the interface exposed to fully managed applications.

```
public:
    literal String^ Foo = "foo";
```

Unfortunately, `literal` requires an immediate value, so using the `std::string` value is not possible. As an alternative, you can create a static read-only property that returns the string.

```
public:
    static property String^ Foo
    {
        String^ get()
        {
            return gcnew String(Foo::FOO.c_str()); 
        }
    }
```

Personally, I believe rewriting the string again and using `literal` is the better option. However, if you are highly concerned about the constant changing (in a newer version, for example), the property will use the version of `FOO` in the native library.